# how to pass null or numeric value to http request variable in jmeter

Tags: casting, jmeter, httprequest

I am having one http request as shown below to which I am passing value from jdbcPreProcessor query.
But it throws ***Could not convert string to integer: ${tooth_1,}.***
 In my case, From my jdbcPreProcessor I will get value either as null or integer. And why this failing is because when my ${tooth_1} fetches value from jdbcPreProcessor , it fetches null to which it treats as string. so where should I do typecasting and how?

Treatments": [
        {

```
        "tooth": "${tooth_1}",


    }
```

],

Answer (score 0):

My expectation is that the application you're testing expects an [Integer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer#Computer_science) and you're trying to send a [String](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_(computer_science)) to it

If the assumption is correct all you need is to remove the quotation marks around this `"${tooth_1}"` so it would look like:

```
"tooth": ${tooth_1},
```

Also make sure that your `${tooth_1}` JMeter Variable exists and has the anticipated value, it can be checked using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script)

Comment: Thank you for response .Yes i am expecting integer, but jdbc preprocessor has a sql query  where my variable name is  tooth_1 that fetches value as either  null or numeric value. This tooth_1  from jdbc preprocessor is being passed to http request  "${tooth_1} ".

Comment: Yes. As you said i already have those sampler in place so value is shown under it. But still its sending value of null as string. Also btw I changed ${tooth_1} from "${tooth_1}" still no luck